# Convert Griuale fingerprint templates to Digital Persona

Tags: fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I have fingerprint templates stored in SQL Server database using Griaule SDK, now I need to migrate to Digital Persona SDK but it raises error when I try to read the templates, of course I think both have different format. My question it is How can I read or convert my templates from Griaule to Digital Persona.

Comment: In which format are your Griaule fingerprint templates saved in? Is it the proprietary Griaule's fingerprint template format?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you need to use a standard format as ISO or ANSI.

To convert from Griaule to ISO or ANSI, please refer :
http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/manual/fingerprint-sdk/programming-reference-guide/fingerprint-sdk-dll-reference-guide/extraction-functions/grcovertemplate

Something like this (depends on Griaule SDK and language):

```
int result;
// set current buffer size for the extract template
_newTpt->_size = GR_MAX_SIZE_TEMPLATE;
result = GrConvertTemplate((char*)_oldTpt, (char*)_newTpt->_tpt, &_newTpt->_size, GR_DEFAULT_CONTEXT, GR_FORMAT_ANSI);

// if error, set template size to 0
if (result < 0){
    // Result < 0 => conversion problem
    _newTpt->_size = 0;
}
```

Template Griaule format are available here : http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/manual/fingerprint-sdk/programming-reference-guide/return-codes-and-constants/template-format

After you have to convert this ISO or ANSI template to Digital Persona Format as this:

```
Fmd fmd = UareUGlobal.GetImporter().ImportFmd(
                    byteArray, Fid.Format.ANSI_381_2004,
                    Format.DP_REG_FEATURES);
```

Comment: @jorgemariomm Is it useful ?

Comment: Yes the conversion it worked fine without errors, but still cant read it in Digital Persona,  I used this link http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/manual/fingerprint-sdk/programming-reference-guide/activex/convert-template because the old application it is in vb .net, I know I'm doing something wrong but can't find it, thanks for your tip

Comment: @jorgemariomm How do you import this template in digital persona , please share code ?

Comment: 'Griaule Convert
'Griaule to ISO finger1 original image finger2 = converted ISO image 
'item it is an identity object with finger1 and finder2 of type System.Data.Linq.Binary
Dim buffer As System.Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Byte), GrFingerXLib.GRConstants.GR_MAX_SIZE_TEMPLATE)
AxGrFingerXCtrl1.ConvertTemplate(item.finger1.ToArray(), buffer, GRConstants.GR_MAX_SIZE_TEMPLATE, GRConstants.GR_DEFAULT_CONTEXT, GRConstants.GR_FORMAT_ISO)
item.finger2 = buffer
…

Comment: 'Verify using Digital Persona
'using finger2 with Digital Persona SDK
Dim template As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template()
template.DeSerialize(item.finger2.ToArray())
ver.Verify(FeatureSet, template, res) 'this rises generic error 0xFFFFFFF8
…
The Verify it works fine if I use a fingerprint saved with Digital Personal instead of Graule converted, I think my error it is in the convert, maybe the buffer array or some serialization, I tried several ways

Comment: @jorgemariomm Is it useful ?

Comment: Hi @LaurentY and again thanks for all your support, yes and no haha, I found that function you said to import the array, and reading the descriptions seems would work, but it is on paid SDK UareUGlobal and I don't have it, just the free Digital Persona SDK, that's my understanding, that's correct?